# Ant design vue different data in nested tables

Tags: vue.js, antd

I'm trying to make nested table, in [documentation](https://www.antdv.com/components/table/#Nested-tables) into the nested table they push one same data, how can i change it and push different data for every parent table row?

```js
<script>
      const columns = [
      { title: 'Status', dataIndex: 'Status', key: 'Status' },
      { title: 'Date', dataIndex: 'DateCreated', key: 'DateCreated' }
    ];

    const innerColumns = [
      { title: 'Price', dataIndex: 'Price', key: 'Price' },
      { title: 'Status', dataIndex: 'Status', key: 'Status' },
    ];

    const data = [
       {
        key: 0,
        "Status": "u",
        "DateCreated": "2019-10-11"
      },
      {
        key: 1,
        "Status": "u",
        "DateCreated": "2019-09-20"
      },
    ];

    const innerData = [
          [
            {
              key: 0,
              "Price": 10623,
              "Status": "u",
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              key: 0,
              "Price": 15084,
              "Status": "u",
            },
            {
              key: 1,
              "Price": 15084,
              "Status": "u",
            }
        ],
    ];
    export default {
      data() {
       return {
        data,
        columns,
        innerColumns,
        innerData,
      };
    },
   };
   </script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="hello">
    <a-table
            :columns="columns"
            :dataSource="data"
            class="components-table-demo-nested">
      <a-table
        slot="expandedRowRender"
        :columns="innerColumns"
        :dataSource="innerData[1]"
        :pagination="false"
      >
      </a-table>
    </a-table>
   </div>
</template>
```

[Here my code](https://codepen.io/amvicc/pen/GRJRvLX)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Linking out to code puts a question at risk if that site goes away. Editing the question to include a [mre] ensures that the question will still be useful over the long term, the same goes for answers.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Template:

```
<a-table :data-source="data" :defaultExpandAllRows="true" v-on:expandedRowsChange="console.log">
    <a-table-column title="First Col" data-index="firstCol" />

    <template v-slot:expandedRowRender="record, index, indent, expanded">
        <a-table :data-source="record.nestedData"
                 :pagination="false">
            <a-table-column title="File Name" data-index="filename" />
        </a-table>
    </template>
</a-table>
```

Script:

```
Vue.component('demo', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            data: [
                {
                    firstCol: '1',
                    nestedData: [{filename: 'nested 11'}, {filename: 'nested 12'}]
                },
                {
                    firstCol: '2',
                    nestedData: [{filename: 'nested 22'}, {filename: 'nested 22'}]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice catch. Your code doesnt work perfectly but put me in the right direct. The three key points are having on the main `<a-table :defaultExpandAllRows="true"`

Using `<template v-slot:expandedRowRender="record">`

And in the sub table `:data-source="record.nestedData">`